# Small portion of screen flickering?

Tags: mac, display, java, eclipse, imac

After running a game in a little window and closing out of it, the location where the window was is giving a very small and very fast flicker. It's not really visible, like you have to look at it to really notice it. Any idea?

It is a 2012, 21.5 inch iMac.  The game is one I made in Java using Eclipse and libGDX.

Comment: Does this happen with all games or that one in specific?  Can you include what game this happens with?

Comment: It was a custom built game I was working on. Something was glitching up in at while I was away. Which my idea was that the high amount of FPS caused something. @DavidStarkey

Comment: If you figured it out never be afraid to answer your own question.  It may help out others in the future.

Comment: Well it's still happening, that was one of my ideas. I just don't know how to resolve it. @DavidStarkey

Comment: Can you include some information on the game?  What language is it in?  Is it fullscreen or windowed?  Are you using a game engine to make it?

Comment: It's all in Java. I was running it in Eclipse emulator. It's windowed. And i'm using libGDX. @DavidStarkey